# Is there a Tree Search function in Python to get all the parent for a given node based on Data, not by Node Id

Tags: python-3.x

Need to search a Tree based on Data.

Tried converting a Tree to Dict and search but did not work as expected. Requirement is to get all the related parent details of a node based on data.

```py
tree = Tree()
tree.create_node(tag="Eatables",identifier="Food",data="Eatables")  # root node
......
tree.create_node(tag="Apple",identifier="Apple1",parent="RF_01",data="Apple")
..............
tree.create_node(tag="Apple",identifier="Apple2",parent="AppJu1",data="Apple")
..............
tree.create_node(tag="Apple",identifier="Apple3",parent="Salad1",data="Apple")
............
tree.show()

Eatables
├── Ingredients
│   ├── Milk
│   ├── Sugar
│   └── Water
├── Processed_Food
│   ├── Apple_Juice
│   │   ├── Apple
│   │   └── Milk
│   └── Salad
│       ├── Apple
│       ├── Banana
│       ├── Beetroot
│       ├── Carrot
│       ├── JackFruit
│       └── Mango
├── Raw_Food
│   ├── Apple
│   ├── Banana
│   ├── Jack_Fruit
│   └── Mango
└── Vegetables
    ├── Beet_root
    └── Carrot
```

Expected output is Node, Parent & grand_parent.
[ [Apple, Raw_food, Eatables],[Apple,Salad,Processed_Food],[Apple,Apple_Juice,Processed_Food] ]

Comment: Which library is this `Tree` imported from?

Comment: from treelib import Node, Tree

Answer (score 0):

By taking nodeid it is possible to get all the required data, fpointer and bpointer are very useful. Starting a search in a Tree data structure without nodeid is not an efficient way.